# Divide a number into n numbers such that sum of n numbers equal to the number

Tags: java, recursion

Let's say the *number* is **2** and *n* is **3**.

The output should be:

`[2, 0, 0][0, 2, 0][0, 0, 2][1, 1, 0][1, 0, 1][1, 0, 1][0, 1, 1]`

if *n* is **2**, the output should be:

`[2, 0][0, 2][1, 1]`

Well, I tried writing a method using recursion and I've pretty much written it successfully.

Here is the method.

```
public static void divideANumberIntoNNumbers(int number, int n) {
    try {
        for (int i = number; i >= 0; --i) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            int x = n - 1;
            if (x > 0) {
                divideANumberIntoNNumbers(number - i, x);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The following are the outputs I got.

When number = 4 and n = 2:

> 4 0
>   3 1
>   2 2
>   1 3
>   0 4

When number = 4 and n = 3:

> 4 0 0
>   3 1 0
>   0 1
>   **2 2 0**
>   **1 1**
>   **0 2**
>   1 3 0
>   2 1
>   1 2
>   0 3
>   0 4 0
>   3 1
>   2 2
>   1 3
>   0 4

In the second output, if you see the highlighted part, the permutations are `2 2 0` and `2 1 1` and `2 0 2`.

I would like to know what modifications I need to make to the method so that I can store the permutations in the data structure `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: May i know your question?

Comment: what is the algorithm you need to follow here? provide more details includes your criteria with n value.

Comment: @javaBeginner Please find the edited question

Comment: @kocko Please find the edited question

Comment: @hemanth Please find the edited question

Answer (score 1):

Without blindly giving you your homework answer, I would suggest using a recursive method to do this.  Basically, you need every combination of every whole number that adds up, so you can assume that 5,3 would be:

```
? + 5
? + 4
? + 3
? + 2
? + 1
? + 0
```

where ? is now equal to the original total (5) minus the right side.  Recurse the ? figuring out all those combination.

Comment: I have already written the method, I would like to know how to store the permutations in the data structure `List<List<Integer>>`

Answer (score -4):

```
if (n == 2) {
    System.out.println("[2, 0][0, 2][1, 1]");
  }
else if (n==3) {
    System.out.println("[2, 0, 0][0, 2, 0][0, 0, 2][1, 1, 0][1, 0, 1][1, 0, 1][0, 1, 1]");
  }
```

But I don't think this will count as a solution to your homework !

Comment: he might want to get the results dynamically